Using inducing points for exact gaussian process inference
I'm a bit muddled with the inference of gaussian processes using inducing points, in particular in conditions when this should be exact inference and not an approximation.
For a gaussian process $f\sim GP(\textbf{0}, \kappa)$ with
$ \kappa :X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a positive definite kernel, and with training data $f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)$, if want to infer the value at a new point $x_*$, we usually perform inference at a cost of $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ to invert the matrix $\kappa(f(x_i), f(x_j))$ for $i,j=1,\dots n$ where $n$ is the number of training points which provides the normal distribution $p(f(x_*)|f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n))$.
My question is about using inducing points to speed up this inference. In particular if we let
$y= f(x_*) + z$ where $z \sim N(0, \varepsilon)$,
then $p(y | f(x_*),f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)) = p(y | f(x_*))$,
But also $\{ f(x) | x \in X\} \cup \{y\}$ is a gaussian process, if we extend $\kappa$ to $X \cup \{x_{**}\}$ the domain with an added point with $f(x_{**}) :=y$, in the natural way (considering it provides the covariance of the GP): $\kappa'(x_{**},x) := \kappa(x_*,x) \text{ for } x\neq x_{**} \text{ and } \kappa'(x_{**},x_{**}) := \kappa(x_{*},x_{*}) + \varepsilon$
So then why can't we use the inducing points method with the inducing point being $x_*$ to infer the value of $f(x_{**})$ in $\mathcal{O}(m^2n) = \mathcal{O}(n)$ time with $m=1$ the number of inducing points, as used here: https://andrewcharlesjones.github.io/journal/inducing-points.html, or in this paper: https://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/nips05spgp.pdf.
In more detail, since we have that $p(y | f(x_*),f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)) = p(y | f(x_*))$ we know that $p(y|f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)) = \int p(y| f(x_*))\ p(f(x_*)|f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n))\ df(x_*)$ and from the right hand side expression we have the form of a gaussian whose parameters we can infer in sub cubic time as in the above links.
Then in this case if $\varepsilon$ is small, we can calculate an approximation to the posterior $p(y|f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n))$ in linear time, which seems impossible, since this should be $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Welcome to the site. I have to admit I'm a little bit confused about the details of your question, but if what you're asking is "If I care only about the function value at a specific point, can I get away with using only one inducing point?", the answer is Yes. Of course, this gives us no guarantees about how the approximating distribution will behave at other locations in the input space. It also will not give us the correct predictive variance.

(We would also have to be careful about the specific variational scheme we are using, because most commonly used variational methods try to approximate the posterior throughout the space).

Thanks for your response! That's what I'm asking yes. To extend the point, we could use this same trick for m points, and then perform inference for these points in O(n*m^2), which could be a significant improvement if the number of points we are trying to infer the posterior over is much less than the number of training points.
By the predictive variance do you mean the variance of p(y| data)? If so I don't understand why the variance given by the single inducing point in my example would be wrong, but the mean would be correct.
